# I Almost have a Unified searchbar in iOS xcode 4.3 but for only one word?

Tags: xcode, url, search

Everything seems to work well except when I try to search more than two words. So, "apple" gets sent to google as a search but "apple stuff" just fails to load. Any ideas? Also, I added the google search to didfailtoload but that returned a loop of didfailtoload.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    webView.delegate = self;

    if ([urlField.text hasPrefix:@"http://"]) {

        [webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlField.text]]];
        [urlField resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;

    } else if ([self isProbablyURL:urlField.text]) {

    NSString *query = [urlField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    NSURL *urlQuery = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", query]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlQuery];
    [webView loadRequest:request]; 
    [urlField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;

    } else {

        ([self performGoogleSearchWithText:urlField.text]);
        [urlField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;

    }
}


- (void)performGoogleSearchWithText:(NSString *)text {

    // Make a google request from text and mark it as not being "fallbackable" on a google search as it is already a Google Search
    NSString *query = urlField.text;
    NSURL *urlQuery = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=%@", query]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlQuery];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

}


- (BOOL)isProbablyURL:(NSString *)text {

     // do something smart and return YES or NO
    NSString *urlRegEx =
    @"((\\w)*|(m.)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|(m.)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:urlField.text];
    //return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `-performGoogleSearchWithText:` you are creating a Google URL with the search string provided by the user.  However, if the query contains multiple words there will be whitespace between the words and NSURL will refuse to create the URL because it would contain invalid characters.  In order for this to work you will have to replace the whitespace characters with the percent escaped equivalent, e.g. %20.

In the following version of the `-performGoogleSearchWithText:` method I have used NSStrings `+stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method to replace characters in the search string that aren't valid in a URL with the URL percent encoded equivalents.

```
- (void)performGoogleSearchWithText:(NSString *)text {
    // Make a google request from text and mark it as not being "fallbackable" on a google search as it is already a Google Search
    NSString *query = [text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *urlQuery = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=%@", query]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlQuery];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Note: I've used the passed in text parameter rather than getting the users query directly from the user interface using `urlField.text`.